# Gurobi - Python: is there a way to express "for some" in a constraint?

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, python, gurobi, constraint

I'm new to Gurobi in Python and I am wondering if there is way to express/code "for some" in the following constraint:

$x_i+x_j +x_k+x_l =2$ for some $i, j, k,l \in \{0,1,2,...., 10\}$,
where $x_i$  are binary variables.

**Question:**
Is there a way to express  the "for some"  $i, j,k,$ and $l$ in a certain set ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The existence of some $4$-subset with sum $2$ is equivalent to having at least two $x_i=1$ and at least two $x_i=0$, so impose $2\le \sum_i x_i \le 9$.